# R - Aggregate Function different Results When Adding new grouping column

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I am a R-beginner and I am stuck and can't find a solution. Any remarks are highly appreciated. Here is the problem:

I have a dataframe df.
The columns are converted to char (Attributes) and num.
I want to reduce the dataframe by using the aggregate function (dply is not an option).

When I am aggregating using

```
df_agg <- aggregate(df["AMOUNT"], df[c("ATTRIBUTE1")], sum)
```

I get correct results. But I want to group by more attributes. When adding more attributes for example

```
df_agg <- aggregate(df["AMOUNT"], df[c("ATTRIBUTE1", "ATTRIBUTE2")], sum)
```

then at some point, the aggegrate result changes. The sum of Amount is no longer equal to the result of the first first aggegration (or the original dataframe).

Has anyone an idea what causes this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Gregor has correctly pointed out that problem could be a grouping variable having `NA`. The `dplyr` handles `NA` in grouping variables differently than `aggregate`.

We have an alternate solution with `aggregate`. Please note that document suggest that

> ```
> `by`   a list of grouping elements, each as long as the variables in the data
>        frame x. The elements are coerced to factors before use.
> ```

Here is clue. You can convert your grouping variables to `factor` using `exclude=""` which will ensure `NA` are part of factor.

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(ATTRIBUTE1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
                 ATTRIBUTE2 = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
                 AMOUNT = 1:10)

df$ATTRIBUTE2[5] <- NA


aggregate(df["AMOUNT"], by = list(factor(df$ATTRIBUTE1,exclude = ""),
                                  factor(df$ATTRIBUTE2, exclude="")), sum)

#   Group.1 Group.2 AMOUNT
# 1       A       a      1
# 2       B       a      2
# 3       B       b      9
# 4       C       b     10
# 5       A       c     10
# 6       B       c     11
# 7       C       c      7
# 8       A    <NA>      5
```

The result when grouping variables are not explicitly converted to `factor` to include `NA` is as:

```
aggregate(df["AMOUNT"], df[c("ATTRIBUTE1", "ATTRIBUTE2")], sum)
#   ATTRIBUTE1 ATTRIBUTE2 AMOUNT
# 1          A          a      1
# 2          B          a      2
# 3          B          b      9
# 4          C          b     10
# 5          A          c     10
# 6          B          c     11
# 7          C          c      7
```

Comment: Using factor and exclude = NULL did the trick for me (exclude = “ “ did not work). Many thanks. And yes there are NA in the respective columns.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you have missing values in some of your grouping columns. Demonstrating on the built-in `mtcars` data, which has no missing values, everything is fine:

```
sum(mtcars$mpg)
# [1] 642.9
sum(aggregate(mtcars["mpg"], mtcars[c("am")], sum)$mpg)
# [1] 642.9
sum(aggregate(mtcars["mpg"], mtcars[c("am", "cyl")], sum)$mpg)
# [1] 642.9
```

But if we introduce a missing value in a grouping variable, it is not included in the aggregation:

```
mt = mtcars
mt$cyl[1] = NA
sum(aggregate(mt["mpg"], mt[c("am", "cyl")], sum)$mpg)
# [1] 621.9
```

The easiest fix would be to fill in the missing values with something other than `NA`, perhaps the string `"missing"`.